# Phillips-Ouliaris test in R by po.test

Tags: cointegration

Phillips-Ouliaris Test is a cointegration test, and in my understanding
it should be commutative. That is, the test result for series x and y and
the test result for series y and x should coincide. However, the `po.test' function in tseries package in R does return different results. Why does this happen?

> po.test(cbind(XUK, XEU))

```
Phillips-Ouliaris Cointegration Test
```

data:  cbind(XUK, XEU)
Phillips-Ouliaris demeaned = -21.662, Truncation lag parameter = 10, p-value =
0.04118

> po.test(cbind(XEU, XUK))

```
Phillips-Ouliaris Cointegration Test
```

data:  cbind(XEU, XUK)
Phillips-Ouliaris demeaned = -17.13, Truncation lag parameter = 10, p-value =
0.09844

For your information, the sample data set is available at:
www.maths.adelaide.edu.au/andrew.metcalfe/Data/us_rates.dat

Comment: In general, given that $y=f(x)$ is a function does not necessarily imply that $x=g(y)$ is also a function.